# SwiftUI @Binding how to confirm the source is updating

Tags: swiftui, binding, didset

Here's an example that demonstrates what I'm seeing:

```
struct Tapper: View {
    @Binding var incrementMe: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button With Binding") {
            incrementMe += 1
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tapCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("didSet tapCount = \(tapCount)")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("tapCount: \(tapCount)")
            Tapper(incrementMe: $tapCount)
                .padding(4.0)
            Button("Button Without Binding") {
                tapCount += 1
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

`ContentView` renders this:

[image]

"Button With Binding" is the button from the `Tapper` struct with the binding back to `tapCount`. "Button Without Binding" is the button from `ContentView` that increments `tapCount` directly (no binding). As far as the view is concerned both buttons appear to work exactly as I would expect.

However, `didSet` is only called for the "Button Without Binding" button. `didSet` is never called for the "Button With Binding" button.

Clearly, `tapCount` *is* being updated from "Button With Binding". When I tap it a few times and then tap "Button Without Binding" `tapCount` increments from its previous value correctly.

Why isn't `didSet` called from the binding? Without `didSet` how can you confirm that a binding is indeed flowing all the way back to the source?

Comment: `Binding` doesn't actually have a value of its own you are using the source of truth. You can use `onChange` to check instead of `didSet`.

Comment: TLDR for the linked post above: you should use `onChange` to observe changes, and `ddiSet` doesn't get called because `incrementMe += 1` isn't calling the setter of `tapCount`. It's just calling the setter of `incrementMe`, and that setter does some SwiftUI magic behind the scenes to change the value of `_tapCount.wrappedValue`.

Comment: @Sweeper ok, I kinda see what's going on behind the scenes but I'm unclear on where I would put onChange to prove that the source was indeed updated. Can you clarify that with a working example?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are so fixated on "proving" the state was indeed updated... Doesn't `Text("tapCount: \(tapCount)")` changing its text prove that? What would count as a "proof" if that isn't a proof? In any case, you can put `onChange(of: tapCount)` in `ContentView`. Just add it as a modifier of the `VStack`.

Comment: @Sweeper I hope I'm more curious than fixated (I'm pretty new to SwiftUI). Re: "Doesn't Text("tapCount: \(tapCount)")". Yeah, I guess but as a newbie the fact that didSet didn't fire left room for some doubt, now replaced by a better understanding of what's going on. Maybe another way to look at my question is what if there was a requirement that this needed to be testable? For your onChange suggestion I guess there could just be an Assert in there.

Comment: If testing is what you want to do, you can easily test this with Xcode's UI testing framework. You can use accessibility APIs to get the `Text`, and assert that it indeed has the desired text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `View` struct is immutable you are really applying the `didSet` to the property wrapper so it only works for that state wrapper and not any other wrappers like the binding one. So, you could just implement `didSet` again for your `@Binding`, e.g.

```
struct Tapper: View {
    @Binding var incrementMe: Int { 
        didSet{
            print("didSet incrementMe = \(incrementMe)")
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button With Binding") {
            incrementMe += 1
        }
    }
}
```

To have the same code run in both `didSet`s you could simply call a func or to have exactly the same code path just move the `tapCount` into a struct, e.g.

```
struct Content {
    var tapCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("didSet tapCount = \(tapCount)")
        }
    }

    // its nice to make funcs for testable logic
    mutating func increment() {
        tapCount += 1
    }
}

struct Tapper: View {
    @Binding var incrementMe: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button With Binding") {
            incrementMe += 1
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var content = Content()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("tapCount: \(content.tapCount)")
            Tapper(incrementMe: $content.tapCount)
                .padding(4.0)
            Button("Button Without Binding") {
                content.increment()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than "You can't use didSet for property wrappers like @State" would it be more accurate to say "You can't use didSet for property wrappers like @State through a binding"? Because in my example didSet is called on tapCount via the button that doesn't use a binding.

Comment: ok I fixed that thanks

Comment: Also, in your version of Tapper that has the didSet did you mean: print("didSet incrementMe = \(incrementMe)")

Comment: Fixed that thanks

Comment: Almost. `print("didSet tapCount = \(incrementMe)")` should be `print("didSet incrementMe = \(incrementMe)")`